# Unable to call web api when constructor have parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have create a web api controller, I have repository pattern so i used Ninject. In constructor i creating Object for interface. Its working fine when i am using it in Normal Controller class. But when i create same in api controller constructor it not working.

Code:

```
//Its not working
IAdminRepository mAdminRepository;
public AccountApiController(IAdminRepository pAdminRepository)
{
    mAdminRepository = pAdminRepository;
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("ValidateLogin")]
public LoginResponse ValidateLogin([FromBody] LoginInfo login)
{
    // some code hare 
}



//But its working
private AccountApiController()
{
}
```

Its working as its have no parameter in constructor. Once again telling u that i have used same parameterized  constructor in Normal controller classes in same project that's working.

Comment: are your constructors actually `private`?

Comment: No its public. Its a typing mistake while posting.

Comment: Did you setup DI for web api? You said you are using Ninject and that it works for normal Controller but WebAPI have a different code stack and would also need to be configured to use that IoC container

Comment: Like Nkosi said, you need to replace either the default DependencyResolver or IHttpControllerActivator the with one that is implemented using your specific IoC container.  Once that's done, you can inject depdencies.  You also need to scan for a different base type than mvc controllers for your api controllers

Comment: @Nkosi could you provide me an example link. As i am new in MVC.